# Django Generating Form with Hidden Input in forloop

Tags: django, django-forms

I have to dynamically populate a form with hidden input in a forloop.
I am doing it like this:
my form class is:

```
class RemoveFromCartForm(forms.Form):
    pass
```

It has no fields, for i intend to use this in order to use class-based views and do form handling.The crux is i am trying to dynamically generate a form with few hidden input as follows:

```
{% for cart_item in cart.cartitems.all %}
<p>{{cart_item}}</p>
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="hidden" name="cartitem" value="{{cart_item.pk}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cart" value="{{cart.pk}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="remove">
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

my views class is as follows:

```
class AddToCart(DetailView, BaseFormView ):
    form_class = RemoveFromCartForm
    model = Cart 
    context_object_name = 'cart'
    template_name = 'cart/add-to-cart.html'

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        return Cart.objects.get(cart_id=self.request.session['CART_ID'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        #return something
```

problem is my form.cleaned_data is {}, though i am using forloop to populate some hidden input on the fly. How can i add those hidden inputs so i get them in my form_valid class ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but notice form_valid() doesn't have a return statement
This is from official django doc ,check the example of overriding form_valid method
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/